# Transforming div's with images in slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html structure

```
<div id="slide">
     <div style=" position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;overflow:hidden;">

        <div class='DS_Banners_Topo' id='DS_Banners_Topo_1'>
            <a href='#' target='_self'><img alt='Slide1' src='http://www.dotstore.com.br/74446_salessuplementos/banners/slide1.jpg' /></a>
        </div>
        <div class='DS_Banners_Topo' id='DS_Banners_Topo_2'>
            <a href='#' target='_self'><img alt='Slide2' src='http://www.dotstore.com.br/74446_salessuplementos/banners/slide2.jpg' /></a>
        </div>
        <div class='DS_Banners_Topo' id='DS_Banners_Topo_3'>
            <a href='#' target='_self'><img alt='Slide3' src='http://www.dotstore.com.br/74446_salessuplementos/banners/slide3.jpg' /></a>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Need to turn this into a slide to change anything in their structure. Keeping your classes. Is it possible to do this in html structure of these?

**DEMO CODE** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/b4YHe/)

Comment: Trying to present this html shaped structure slide through some jquery plugin http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/b4YHe/

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/NcPjg/1/

Comment: @user3743128 i dont see no javascript at all, you should change question title to "could someone pls build me a slider?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to change you structure, but can change the css, here is an example of what you could do:

**CSS**

```
#slide {
    margin: 22px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slide>div{
    position: relative;
}

.DS_Banners_Topo{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.DS_Banners_Topo img{
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //current slide index
    var counter = 0,
    slides = $('.DS_Banners_Topo');

    //position slides
    slides.each(function(i,e){ $(this).css('left',i-1+'00%'); });

    //change slide every 1000ms
    setInterval(function(){
        counter = counter>slides.length-3 ? 0 : ++counter;
        $('#slide>div').animate({'left':-counter+'00%'});
    },1000);

});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Note that I removed the unwanted inline styles for the div inside `#slide`

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to use jQuery or another library to easily rotate the visibility on each of these divs. Just Google jQuery Carousel and you'll find and endless amount of solutions to your issue. Most will preserve all existing classes.

Comment: Google jQuery Carousel uses a structure of `<ul>` and `<li>` to operate the slide, I need that it can adapt my html structure that I have.